# get user input from comboBox and bind to two variables from different classes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

So i just started wpf a few months ago and now i want to get user input from a comboBox and bind it to two variables such that when selectedItem changes, the two variables will also be reflect the change.

The error i am facing now is this:

System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '_institution' property not found on 'object' ''ObjectDataProvider' (HashCode=22018304)'. BindingExpression:Path=_institution; DataItem='ObjectDataProvider' (HashCode=22018304); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='institutionCB'); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object')

and i have no idea what it says.

```
<Windows.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="institutionData" MethodName="GetValues"  ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:Institutions"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="userInputData" ObjectType="{x:Type local:userInputData}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <sys:String>_institution</sys:String>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="commonServiceModel" ObjectType="{x:Type local:ServiceCommonModel}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <sys:String>_institution</sys:String>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <local:Converter x:Key="Converter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

converter is in my code behind:

```
public class Converter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object[] { value, value };
    }
}
```

and this is my comboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="institutionCB" HorizontalAlignment ="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22" Width="51" Margin="5,27,0,0" Background="White" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource institutionData}}" Tag="Institution">
    <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource userInputData}" Path="_institution" BindsDirectlyToSource="True" Mode="OneWayToSource"/>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource commonServiceModel}" Path="_institution" BindsDirectlyToSource="True" Mode="OneWayToSource"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: How are the properties you're trying to bind to defined? Are they dependency properties?

Comment: private string with get method->        public String _institution;
       public String Institution { get { return _institution; } set { _institution = value; OnPropertyChanged("Institution"); } }